# How to programmatically get the "mean error in pixels" displayed in the reprojection errors in the camera calibrator app?

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I'm looking for a function or set of steps to get the same values that are displayed in the reprojection errors figure in the camera calibrator app. The y-axis is in "mean error in pixels" and looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to calculate them with:

```
[undistortedPoints,reprojectionErrors] = undistortPoints(imagePoints, params);
err = mean(reprojectionErrors);
```

(per image) the calculated err is many order of magnitude lower than the ones I get using the app: for the first image I got err=6.8850e-11, while the first bar in the figure looks more like 0.15.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`histogram(reprojectionErrors, 200)`

Which displays a more accurate histogram (with 200 bins).

Or maybe try print the reprojectionError values..